# Can Sheet-A reference a total that might come from 2 different Sheets (B&C), but display the total from the Sheet (A or B) currently being used?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would appreciate it if the experts can tell me whether or not it will be possible to do what I would like to!

Here at the University of Johannesburg Library, I have put in place a simple system in order to count and capture students detail when entering & exciting the Libraries.
(In order to control numbers due to Covid)

**So I have 3 separate Google Excel files.**

File-1 with Sheet-1 runs on a PC where students Enter the Library
File-2 with Sheet-1 runs on a PC where students Exit the Library
File-3 with Sheet-1 runs on a big 65” screen above Circulation – displaying the total number of Students in the Library (simple formula that minus File-2’s total from that of File-1)

**Then I have 2 scripts running on Files 1 & 2:**

Script-1 (TimeStamp) to trigger on Edit, so that I capture date/time when a student swipe his/her card and enter or exit the Library.
Script-2 (Copy & Clean) that runs  1AM to copy the previous day’s data to backup files and then clean Files-1 & 2

**Problem:**

For some reason this Copy & Clean script will run fine for a week and then suddenly stop.
This means that the next day, Files-1 & 2 will not be fresh/clean.
So I have created a 2nd sheet for files-1 & 2 that I called “Emergency” on which staff can then click and students can scan their cards.
(This will give me time to clean Sheets-1 manually)

However, if staff uses the “Emergency” sheets, obviously File-3 will still display the numbers coming from Sheets-1.

**Question:**

Is there a way that one can program Sheet-3 to display the totals coming from the “Emergency” sheets, when they are in used?
And then again from Sheets-1 when they are normally in use?

Comment: What do you mean by "the script will suddenly stop"? Do you have any errors associated with this? Are you using a trigger? Moreover, can you share the code you are using as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use a Time-Based Trigger for the "myCopySheet" script that runs between 01h00 and 02h00 AM

Script to copy the content of the "Enter" sheet to a backup sheet and then to clear the "Enter" sheet

Error:

[image]

"myCopySheet":

```
function myCopySheet() {
// source spreadsheets
var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
// Get previous days date for the new tab
var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var now = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
var date = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-dd")

var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
// Change ID to destination Sheet - One for Entry and one for Exit
var destSpreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('15bev166RYSHNlWhnLIBHNtLVMbQyWjzJDOW0R-NBIOg');

// Copy to new spreadsheet sheet 
srcSheet.copyTo(destSpreadsheet).setName(date);

// Clear Sheet Column A
var firstCell = srcSheet.getRange("A2");
var numRows = srcSheet.getLastRow()+1;
var range = srcSheet.getRange(firstCell.getRow(), firstCell.getColumn(), numRows);
range.clear();

// Clear Sheet Column B
var firstCell = srcSheet.getRange("B2");
var numRows = srcSheet.getLastRow()+1;
var range = srcSheet.getRange(firstCell.getRow(), firstCell.getColumn(), numRows);
range.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The error message `Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ID` you are receiving might in fact be related to this known issue on Google's side.**

I suggest you star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211) as all the updates regarding this will be posted there.